# My Sequelize BelongsToSetAssociationMixin hangs perpetually when i try to use it. How do I fix it?

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I am trying to add a RefreshToken with with an association to a specific Account in my PostgreSQL db using Sequelize. But the command to create the association hangs for several minutes.

The two tables have a relationship defined like this:

```
    Account.hasMany(RefreshToken, {
        as: "refresh_token_owner",
        foreignKey: "refresh_token_owner_id",
    });
    RefreshToken.belongsTo(Account, { as: "refresh_token", foreignKey: "refresh_token_id" });
```

Here is how I defined my mixins:

```
import { Account, AccountId } from "./Account";

export class RefreshToken extends Model<RefreshTokenAttributes, RefreshTokenCreationAttributes> implements RefreshTokenAttributes {

    getAccount!: Sequelize.BelongsToGetAssociationMixin<Account>;
    setAccount!: Sequelize.BelongsToSetAssociationMixin<Account, AccountId>;
    createAccount!: Sequelize.BelongsToCreateAssociationMixin<Account>;

    static initModel(sequelize: S): typeof RefreshToken {
    // snip
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to use `setAccount` here to say that "the account associated with this refresh token is this one":

```
 public createRefreshToken = async (id: number, token: string, expires: Date, createdByIp: string) => {
        const associatedAcct: Account | null = await this.accountDAO.getAccountById(id);
        if (associatedAcct === null) throw Error("Account not found");
        const rt: RefreshToken = await RefreshToken.create({
            token,
            expires,
            createdByIp,
            isActive: true,
        });
        console.log(rt, "38rm"); // logs
        rt.setAccount(associatedAcct);  
        console.log("account set", "40rm");  // doesn't log, even after minutes
        return rt;
    };
```

I do not get any error message. I just get a notification that my Jest tests have timed out after 240 seconds.

edit3: per Anatoly's request, here I have turned on logging like this, because thats how they say to do it in [the docs](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js%7Esequelize):

```
import { TEST_DB_HOST, TEST_DB_NAME, TEST_DB_PASSWORD, TEST_DB_PORT, TEST_DB_USER } from "../config";

export const testDatabase = new Sequelize({
    dialect: "postgres",
    host: TEST_DB_HOST,
    port: TEST_DB_PORT,
    database: TEST_DB_NAME,
    username: TEST_DB_USER,
    password: TEST_DB_PASSWORD,
    logging: (...msg) => console.log(msg),
});
```

Ctrl F "options.logging" to see the docs tell you to do it like this.

But i don't see the logging of SQL statements like I expect. So I am stuck again

edit4: I thought maybe my Sequelize was initialized incorrectly so I tried this:

```
// const testDatabase = new Sequelize({
//     dialect: "postgres",
//     host: TEST_DB_HOST,
//     port: TEST_DB_PORT,
//     database: TEST_DB_NAME,
//     username: TEST_DB_USER,
//     password: TEST_DB_PASSWORD,
//     // logging: console.log,// this didnt' work
// });

const testDatabase = new Sequelize("postgres", "postgres", "postgres", {
    host: TEST_DB_HOST,
    dialect: "postgres",
    logging: console.log,
});
```

because the docs say ["Option 3: Passing parameters separately (other dialects)"](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/)

Comment: Seems like you forgot to use `await` with `setAccount`

Comment: I added the line `await rt.setAccount(associatedAcct);` and it still just hangs there.

Comment: Turn on SQL logging and look what operation causes this hanging.